# How to automatically select save button when creating a PDF using

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba

I have my code working well and creating a PDF from the worksheet. But I want this to happen without having to press the save radio button for the filepath.
Or is it that I need to to create an exact filename and save without choice

[image]

```
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet
    strTime = Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy\_hhmm")

    strPath = wbA.Path
    If strPath = "" Then
      strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If
    strPath = strPath & "\"

    strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
    strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

    strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
        (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
            FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
            Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    If myFile <> "False" Then
        wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False _

        'confirmation message with file info
        MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
          & vbCrLf _
          & myFile
    End If

exitHandler:
    CommandButton2.Visible = True
    CommandButton1.Visible = False     
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want the save dialog you need to specify the full path at `Filename:=myFileWithFullPath` in `ExportAsFixedFormat`. So it saves the file directly without choosing. If you need to choose the path with the dialog then you need to press the save button yourself.

Answer (score 1):

create an exact filename at run time and save for eg:-

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _ 
Type:=xlTypePDF _
Filename:= destfolder & PDF_Filename _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
IncludeDocProperties:=True _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: but @tim should use `wsA` instead of `ActiveSheet` in this answer. It was a very good decision to define the active worksheet as `wsA` first.

Comment: @Peh... yes,  by activesheet i meant the same...i just shared it as a sample code...

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following:

```
Application.SendKeys("%s")
```

The above Sends keystrokes to the active application here it means Alt+S which is shortcut for Save...